# Precedence of ui:param vs bean name

Tags: jsf, el, facelets

What has higher precedence in el context?

### Example

Two managed beans one for admin and one for client:

Admin: `@ManagedBean(name = "fooEditBean")`
Client: `@ManagedBean(name = "clientFooEditBean")`

**Include file `incl_fooEdit.xhtml`:**

```
#{fooEditBean.bar}
```

**Site admin:**

```
<ui:include src="incl_fooEdit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="fooEditBean" value="#{fooEditBean}/>
</ui:include>
```

**Site client:**

```
<ui:include src="incl_fooEdit.xhtml">
    <ui:param name="fooEditBean" value="#{clientFooEditBean}/>
</ui:include>
```

Which managed bean will *Site client* use?

*One could simply use `adminFooEditBean` or a different param name.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one which is put later in EL scope has precedence. So it's basically last-in-first-out.

In this case, the `<ui:param>` value is put later, so it will have precedence in the code which runs inside the context of `<ui:include>`.

Note however that older JSF impl versions may have problems with "resetting" the EL scope after the code leaves the context wherein the new EL variable is being set, which would in this particular example cause that the code *after* `<ui:include>` still gets the `<ui:param>` value. If you're facing this problem, just upgrading the JSF impl should do.